# Grunt : Fatal error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I have read this question [Gruntjs: Fatal error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422697/gruntjs-fatal-error-getaddrinfo-enotfound)

But it won't work on me.

My gruntfile use `localhost` as `hostname` just like default from yeoman `yo backbone`. Here is my gruntfile:
http://pastebin.com/1T9vaUVV

Whether I use `grunt connect` or `grunt server` my terminal always return `Fatal error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`. Here is my terminal output: http://pastebin.com/fSGr2qvE

Is anyone have solution? thanks.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using '0.0.0.0' as the hostname instead; like so:

```
connect: {
  options: {
    base: 'app/',
    hostname: '0.0.0.0'
  }
}
```